# Find Coin's unfairness with only 4 tosses

Tags: mathematics, probability

There is a unfair coin and you want to find out its actual probability, to find the exact probability is actually not an easy task, you need to toss it many many times to get the close to actual result.

Gladly, someone has already calculated that and he is observing you while you are tossing. You toss the coin 4 times at the beginning, and get 2 tails and 2 heads as ***THTH***. Then all of a sudden the observer said:

> The chance of getting $2$ *tails* and $2$ *heads* with this coin is actually *half of the probability of getting a tail* in a single toss with it.

By this information,

> Can you find the most probable probability of getting a tail in a single toss with this coin?

Comment: The chance of getting 2 tails and 2 heads - in the THTH pattern or any pattern?

Comment: @boboquack...oh...so many dirty jokes can be spawned from your comment.

Comment: @boboquack: since "2 tails and 2 heads" already clashes with the THTH pattern; I would infer that the order of outcomes is not relevant. (and if the statement is not related to having flipped the THTH pattern, that means the THTH serves no narrative purpose whatsoever, which seems counterintuitive)

Comment: I find this to be very amusing, since it's impossible to bias a coin: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/Papers/dice.pdf

Comment: @MechMK1 yes you cant find it but get close to the actual probability as I stated in the question as "you need to toss it many many times to get close to actual result."

Comment: @Oray I am not good enough in math to actually solve your puzzle, but my comment was merely an interesting piece of trivia

Comment: "*Find Coin's unfairness*" - President Coin certainly was unfair, but it took a while for her unfairness to be found.

Comment: @Randal'Thor :)) English is not my mother tongue, thanks for understanding.

Comment: Given that there is more than one possibility, I think the only reasonable answer to "can you find the actual probability of getting a tail in a single toss with this coin?" is "no" (Which makes this question a bit boring. Maybe change it to "most likely probability" instead?)

Comment: @ffao agreed... I did not want to edit the question after a proper answer is given, but I think it will be okay to change it at this point.

Comment: @MechMK1: Interesting article - but I'm pretty sure there do exist [ways of biasing a coin](https://www.amazon.com/Loftus-Two-Headed-Quarter/dp/B0016ZN17C) ;-)

Comment: @psmears I wouldn't really call it a bias. In layman's terms, a bias in an increase in probability, not an impossibility for something to occur. So yes, it really is impossible to make a coin that has a heads/tails ratio of, say, 40:60

Comment: @MechMK1: So a judging panel that always awards *all* the points to one team, and not the other, regardless of merit, isn't biased? A two-headed coin does increase the probability of heads - it increases it to one. (But I agree that's outside the scope of the paper - I wasn't being 100% serious, hence the smiley:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability of getting tails.

We are told that

> $\frac{1}{2}p=p^2(1-p)^2\binom 42\implies 12p-24p^2+12p^3-1=0\text{ or }p=0$ by rearranging.

This expression doesn't have a nice factorisation, so plugging it into the cubic formula, we get (given that $0\leq p\leq1$)

> $p = \frac{1}{12} \left(8 + \frac{-4 - 4 i\sqrt3}{\sqrt[3]{1 + 3 i \sqrt7}} + i (\sqrt3 + i) \sqrt[3]{1 + 3 i \sqrt7}\right)$
>  or
> $p=\frac{1}{12} \left(8 + \frac{4i(\sqrt3+i)}{\sqrt[3]{1 + 3 i \sqrt7}} + (-i\sqrt3 - 1) \sqrt[3]{1 + 3 i \sqrt7}\right)$

Now, these aren't very nice numbers. But they are approximately:

> $0.1037$ and $0.6388$

In reality, I think that:

> the solution from the first spoiler, $p=0$, is most likely as such a finely calibrated coin would be impossible, or at least $p$ is infinitesimal (since supposedly we did flip tails)

even though

> from the data given, that we did flip two heads and tails, the root at $p\approx0.6388$ is most likely.

Comment: Nice work. Now, which one of these two seems more reasonable ;)

Comment: In my opinion, in reality, you cannot have two tails with p is close to 0. I would go for 0.6388 since I got two tails in 4 rolls. I wish I would have asked in that way :)

Comment: Since you did get a tail, it can't be p=0.

Comment: I'd say the 0.6388 is the most likely. This is the one that is most likely to produce the two tails and two heads that we saw as we flipped our coins.

Comment: Regardless of whether you consider p=0 possible or not, the answer is clearly **No, you can't tell**, since there are at least two possibilities that can't be ruled out.

Comment: @boboquack could you edit your answer with the latest change if possible?

Comment: Why would p=0 be most likely?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer** As per the comment of Jaap Scherphuis the equation of this answer equation is incorrect. Thread carefully

Gave wolfram alpha:

> 1/x*1/(1-x)*1/x*1/(1-x) = 2/x

And got back:

> x = 1.5652

Which gives

> Chance of tails ~64%

Thoughts:

> hmm i remember seeing the numberphile video about TH ordering and how it mattered!, I reject this and stand by my solution! I'd be interested to have flaws pointed out though. :)

Comment: The $1/(1-x)$ factors should be $1-1/x$ because if $p=1/x$ is the probability of tails then the probability of heads is $q=1-p=1-1/x$. Oddly enough, the answer from your incorrect equation turns out to be exactly the same as the correct answer for 2H and 2T in any order!

Comment: Ofcourse that's correct. Classic, correct result even when doing significant mistakes! That's maths for you ^^